# neo4j 2.1.7: How can I index my current data which was there before

Tags: database, indexing, neo4j, cypher

I had an old schema and imported a new schema to db, and tried to apply the indexes from the new schema also on the old schema

I created the indexes, and I wrote a cypher which is influenced by this indexes, but it took a long time until it returned an answer.

What I've tried to do in order to solve it - 
I understand that after I create the index, only the data after I created the index would be indexed.
I also tried to write some cyphers which need to trigger the index, but it didn't work.

tl;dr -
How can I trigger those indexes on the old scheme?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for perhaps you can share the indexes, queries and new structure in more detail?

Comment: Usually is `CREATE INDEX ON :Label(property);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:SCHEMA` command in the Neo4j browser to see what indexes have been created and their current status (if they are online or still being built).

For example, this is the result of running `:SCHEMA` in the Neo4j browser for a simple graph with only one index:

```
:SCHEMA

Indexes
  ON :Tag(title) ONLINE  

No constraints
```